# How do I apply a class to an active Angular Material tab based on a property?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a property called editMode.  How to apply this CSS class to only the active tab when editMode is true?

```
.tab-active-edit-mode {
  border-top: none !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0078d2 !important;
  background-color: #dddddd !important;
}
```

This is what Chat GPT gave as an answer but it seems clunky.  Is there a better Angular way?

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.updateTabStyles();
  }

  updateTabStyles() {
    if (this.editMode) {
      // Directly manipulate the DOM to add CSS class to the active tab
      const activeTab = (this.tabGroup._elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).querySelector('.mat-mdc-tab-group .mat-mdc-tab-active');
      if (activeTab) {
        activeTab.classList.add('tab-active-edit-mode');
      }
    } else {
      // Remove the class if not in edit mode
      const tabElements = (this.tabGroup._elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).querySelectorAll('.mat-mdc-tab-group .mat-mdc-tab');
      tabElements.forEach(tab => {
        tab.classList.remove('tab-active-edit-mode');
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use ngClass? This allows you to add classes in your template based on your editing property value

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="selectedTabIndex = $event">
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span [ngClass]="{'tab-active-edit-mode': editing && selectedTabIndex === 0}"
        >Tab 1</span
      >
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span [ngClass]="{'tab-active-edit-mode': editing && selectedTabIndex === 1}"
        >Tab 2</span
      >
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span [ngClass]="{'tab-active-edit-mode': editing && selectedTabIndex === 2}"
        >Tab 3</span
      >
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and add "selectedTabIndex = 0;" to your class.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: I thought of that but it should only apply to the active tab.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-material-jktgkt?file=app%2Ftabs-overview-example.html

Here is a StackBlitz showing the idea. Here the class that is added changes the current tab's text to red, but only if editing is true.